# Why is a characteristic function continuous at $0$?

Tags: continuity, characteristic-functions

My lecture notes say:

> $t \mapsto \exp(-t^2/2)$ is a characteristic function (of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$), so it is clear that it is continuous at $0$.

So why does "being a characteristic function" imply "being continuous at $0$".

I think it should be something very obvious, but I do not get it.

Comment: That is not a characteristic function.

Comment: Do you mean distribution function instead of characteristic function?

Comment: no, I mean characteristic function, so $E[e^{itX}]=\exp(-t^2/2)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ if $X$ is standard normal. Do I get something wrong?

Comment: This is also what Wikipedia states: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Comment: Just a curiosity: Are they really proving that $\exp(-t^2/2)$ is continuos by using the fact that is a characteristic function? Talk about using a cannon to kill a fly :P

Comment: @Ant Not really. We are in the context of characteristic functions. And we want to prove CLT. There we show that the characteristic function converges to $exp(-t^2/2)$ and by Levy's continuity theorem the result follows. It is mentioned that by direct inspection or since it is a characteristic function, we can conclude that indeed it is continuous at 0, so Levy's continuity theorem applies.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi et al: This is one of those terminology things - in probability the "characteristic function" of a random variable is (more or less) the Fourier transform of the distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic function of any random variable is continuous. Say $X$ is a random variable and $t_n\to t$. Then $$\Bbb E[e^{it_n X}]\to\Bbb E[e^{it X}]$$by the Dominated Convergence Theorem.